# How to concat all elements of a STRUCT with more than 1000 elements in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe as shown below with a `struct` field.

```
val arrayStructData = Seq(
Row("James",Row("Java","XX",120)),
Row("Michael",Row("Java","",200)),
Row("Robert",Row("Java","XZ",null)),
Row("Washington",Row("","XX",120))
)

val arrayStructSchema = new StructType().add("name",StringType).add("my_struct", new StructType().add("name",StringType).add("author",StringType).add("pages",IntegerType))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(arrayStructData),arrayStructSchema)


df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my_struct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pages: integer (nullable = true)

df.show(false)

+----------+---------------+
|name      |my_struct      |
+----------+---------------+
|James     |[Java, XX, 120]|
|Michael   |[Java, , 200]  |
|Robert    |[Java, XZ,]    |
|Washington|[, XX, 120]    |
+----------+---------------+
```

I want to construct an output column called `final_list` which shows me absence or presence of elements in the struct. The problem is, that the struct elements are just limited to 3 in this example but in actual data there are a 1,000 elements in the struct and every record may or may not contain values in each element.

Here is how I want to construct the column -

```
val cleaned_df = spark.sql(s"""select name, case when my_struct.name = "" then "" else "name" end as name_present
, case when my_struct.author = "" then "" else "author" end as author_present 
, case when my_struct.pages = "" then "" else "pages" end as pages_present 
from df""")
cleaned_df.createOrReplaceTempView("cleaned_df")
cleaned_df.show(false)
+----------+------------+--------------+-------------+
|name      |name_present|author_present|pages_present|
+----------+------------+--------------+-------------+
|James     |name        |author        |pages        |
|Michael   |name        |              |pages        |
|Robert    |name        |author        |pages        |
|Washington|            |author        |pages        |
+----------+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

So I write a `case` statement for every column to capture its presence or absence. And then I do the concat like below to get final output -

```
val final_df = spark.sql(s"""
select name, concat_ws("," , name_present, author_present, pages_present) as final_list
from cleaned_df
""")
final_df.show(false)
+----------+-----------------+
|name      |final_list       |
+----------+-----------------+
|James     |name,author,pages|
|Michael   |name,,pages      |
|Robert    |name,author,pages|
|Washington|,author,pages    |
+----------+-----------------+
```

I cannot write a giant case statement to capture this for a 1,000 element struct. Is there a smarter way to do this ? Perhaps a UDF ?

I am using Spark 2.4.3. I dont know if there is any higher order functions that support this. But the schema of my real dataframe looks like below -

```
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my_struct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element3: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element5: double (nullable = true)
 .....
 .....
 |    |-- element1000: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: How are you creating a Row with 1000 Row elements in the first place? You may want to rethink your design there.

Comment: that is streaming data coming in as mentioned here - https://github.com/AdobeDocs/analytics-1.4-apis/blob/master/docs/live-stream-api/metrics_dimensions.md and I am interested in evar1-250 and event1-1000 columns shown in that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned already an UDF. With an UDF you can iterate over all fields of my_struct and collect the flags:

```scala
def availableFields = (in:Row) => {
  val ret = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]
  for( i <- Range(0, in.size)) {
    if( !in.isNullAt(i) && in.get(i) != "") {
      ret += in.schema.fields(i).name
    }
  }
  ret.mkString(",")
}
val availableFieldsUdf = udf(availableFields)

df.withColumn("final_list", availableFieldsUdf(col("my_struct")) ).show(false)
```

prints

```
+----------+---------------+-----------------+
|name      |my_struct      |final_list       |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+
|James     |[Java, XX, 120]|name,author,pages|
|Michael   |[Java, , 200]  |name,pages       |
|Robert    |[Java, XZ,]    |name,author      |
|Washington|[, XX, 120]    |author,pages     |
+----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `UDF`.

**Schema**

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- my_struct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- author: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pages: integer (nullable = true)
```

**Constructing Expression**

```
scala> 
val expr = df
    .select("my_struct.*") // Extracting struct columns.
    .columns
    .map(c => (c, trim(col(s"my_struct.${c}")))) // Constructing tupes ("name", trim(col("my_struct.name")))
    .map(c => when(c._2.isNotNull and c._2 =!= "",lit(c._1))) // Checking Not Null & Empty values.

expr: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(CASE WHEN ((trim(my_struct.name) IS NOT NULL) AND (NOT (trim(my_struct.name) = ))) THEN name END, CASE WHEN ((trim(my_struct.author) IS NOT NULL) AND (NOT (trim(my_struct.author) = ))) THEN author END, CASE WHEN ((trim(my_struct.pages) IS NOT NULL) AND (NOT (trim(my_struct.pages) = ))) THEN pages END)
```

**Applying Expression to DataFrame**

```
scala> df.withColumn("final_list",concat_ws(",",expr:_*)).show
+----------+---------------+-----------------+
|      name|      my_struct|       final_list|
+----------+---------------+-----------------+
|     James|[Java, XX, 120]|name,author,pages|
|   Michael|  [Java, , 200]|       name,pages|
|    Robert|    [Java, XZ,]|      name,author|
|Washington|    [, XX, 120]|     author,pages|
+----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: one question @Srinivas  instead of having 2 map functions, wouldn't be better to have just `map(c => when(length(col(s"my_struct.${c}")) > 0, lit(c)))`?

Comment: to be honest I think the more simple an expression is the more readable